# WriteLine isn't shown the message in Output. Selenium. C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I've already tried all options that I've found. It doesn't run. 
No messages in "Output", "Command Window" windows of VS.
Any ideas why?

**Code**:

```
namespace TestTrainee
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    { 
        public LoginPage mainPage;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUpDrvier()
        {
            mainPage = new LoginPage(new ChromeDriver());
        }

        [Test, Order(0)]
        public void CheckLogIn()
        {
            mainPage.OpenPage();
            mainPage.FindElementByXpath(By.XPath("//a[@href='../articles_popup.php']")).Click();
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            mainPage.SwitchPAge();
            Debug.WriteLine("!!!");
            Trace.WriteLine("!!!");
            Console.WriteLine("!!!");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void FinishExe()
        {
            //mainPage.CloseBrowser();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output can be accessed from the Output link in a small panel below the Test Explorer panel after using `Console.WriteLine()`. Create a simple test like the below

```
[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Right-click and run it from the Test Explorer panel in the Visual Studio IDE. Once it completes, make sure you have the SimpleTest selected and you will see in the bottom left corner a small panel indicating that the test has passed, the elapsed time, and a link "Output".

[image: Test explorer results panel]

If you click on that Output link, you will see the results.

[image: Output]

Comment: Having said this... I would recommend you use the NUnit asserts to log messages on pass or fail so that it's all rolled up into a single location instead of spread throughout each of the individual test run results.

Comment: It runs, thanks! Do you mean to save all messages, let's say, in one file?

Comment: Yes, if you do it this way, you will have to click each test run and then click Output to see the results. If you add asserts, you can run all tests with NUnit and then see all the messages in the single results file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

In the `Output` window you need to select `Tests` from the `Show output from` dropdown

[image]